# Intel Ivy Bridge Z77 Driver for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel

I was wondering where I can get the repository for the latest Intel Z77 chipset from?

I've got the new Intel Ivy Bridge 3570K along with with the built in HD4000 video card.

12.04 keeps freezing randomly. Whether I'm browsing, encoding a video, or watching YouTube.

The other thing I noticed in System Setting is that the Graphic Card isn't identified as Intel HD4000, whereas it was in 11.10.

I'm going to use this PC mainly for HTPC, so I need to make sure that all the hardware acceleration is maintained if I have a driver installed.

I found https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates but they don't seen to mention anything about the Z77 chipset.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r` run from the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your replies everyone.

My question was answered at the Ubuntu forum to which one of the members recommended upgrading my kernel to avoid the random freeze-up issues. Once I upgraded into the latest stable 3.3.7 kernel, the video card is now identified and the freeze up has stopped too.

Answer (score 2):

I found this bug.  [Bug #993187](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/993187) According to Launchpad it is fixed by kernel 3.3.6.

I have a SandyBridge desktop (Chipset C200).  While I didn't notice the freezing, my gpu was not identified in 12.04 either and was in 11.10.  While searching for a solution I found one of the Linux blogs recommend installing "mesa-utils" with the cmd line

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

When I did my chipset was identified as Sandybridge Desktop.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Please note that the GPU not being identified in System Settings is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-control-center/+bug/914631) and can be safely ignored--even if the GPU is recognized and working perfectly it will still not show up in system settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question was answered at the Ubuntu forum to which one of the members recommended upgrading my firmrware to avoid the random freeze-up issues. Once I upgraded into the latest stable 3.3.7 kernel, the video card is now identified. http://partiallysanedeveloper.blogsp...ux-freeze.html

Comment: @adempewolff  :Thank you for that info, I didn't see that page when I was searching for my own GPU... But Mesa was still needed for my card; until I installed it my screen was just a little to large so the last little bit to the left was not auto-adjusted correctly...i.e. the arrows that showed an open window would not show until I opened a window and then manually hit the auto adjust on my monitor.....

Comment: The link to the solution above is broken! But I think I found it. Definitely useful, thanks!
http://partiallysanedeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/ivy-bridge-hd4000-linux-freeze.html