# Graphic driver support for Z77 chipset

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I just bought a Shuttle PC (type: SZ77R5) with a Intel Z77 chipset. The graphic device is integrated on the motherboard and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and the grahpic quality is really bad.

I can adjust my screen resolution to maximum of 1024 x 768.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146131/intel-iv-bridge-z77-driver-for-ubuntu-12-04) question but it looks like I did not really help for me. I have upgraded the Linux kernel to: Linux kees-spc 3.3.7-999-optimus and installed mesa-utils, but I doesn't change anything.

In the hardware details screen I see 'Intel® Ivybridge Desktop' is shown as grahpic driver.

Could anyone give me a advise our tell what I should do? Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not really (I guess) the drivers but Ubuntu didn't detected my monitor is supporting any resolution higher then 1024x768.

I first installed the correct driver with:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Then when you go to "details" from the unity launcher, you'll see "Intel® Ivybridge Desktop" as driver for your graphics card. I also tried kernel 3.3.7 as suggested by some others but with no succes and also I am getting system failures with that kernel. Then kernel I currently use is:

```
uname -a
3.2.0-26-generic
```

Then I tried to get it working by adding a xorg.conf file in the /etc/X11/ directory but with no succes (it looked like it didn't take any effect). I did that after reading [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution/) page.

Finally I tried to add a new mode with the `xrandr` tool and that worked. I created a `.xprofile` file in my home dir with the contents below and now after booting my Ubuntu the resolution is perfect.

My `.xprofile` content:

```
cvt 1440 900 60
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1440x900_60.00"
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1440x900_60.00"
```

Note: Just can't just copy the above content. It depends on what you have connected (DVI, HDMI, VGA0/1, etc and which resolution you want to run.